# Concatenating Rows and Delimiting With Special Characters SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table, sorted.

```
ID    Value     Amount
A       2        10.00
A       3         4.25 
B       6         2.01
B       7         5.00 
B       9         9.00
B       11        4.25
C       8         10.00
C       6         4.00
```

How can I get:

```
ID    Col1           Col2
A    [2-3]          [10.00-4.25]
B    [6-7],[9-11]   [2.01-5.00], [9.00-4.25]
C    [8-6]          [10.00-4.00]
```

I know this can be with FOR XML PATH if I am only delimiting by commas, but
I don't know how to insert for only pairs of values.

Comment: How do you determine the grouping? Is it by twos?

Comment: Yes, only pairs of consecutive data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to group them by twos. The idea is to concatenate rows with `-` first, and then concatenate them again by `,`.

```
;WITH CteGrouping AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value) + 1) / 2
    FROM SampleData
)
,CteDash AS(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Col1 = STUFF((
            SELECT '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Value)
            FROM CteGrouping t2
            WHERE 
                t2.ID = t1.ID
                AND t2.RN = t1.RN
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1 , 1, ''),
        Col2 = STUFF((
            SELECT '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Amount)
            FROM CteGrouping t2
            WHERE 
                t2.ID = t1.ID
                AND t2.RN = t1.RN
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1, 1, '')
    FROM CteGrouping t1
    GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.RN
)
,CteBracket AS(
    SELECT
        ID,
        Col1 = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + '[' + Col1 + ']'
            FROM CteDash t2
            WHERE 
                t2.ID = t1.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1 , 1, ''),
        Col2 = STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + '[' + Col2 + ']'
            FROM CteDash t2
            WHERE 
                t2.ID = t1.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1, 1, '')
    FROM CteDash t1
    GROUP BY t1.ID
)
SELECT * FROM CteBracket
```

**RESULT**

```
| ID |         COL1 |                    COL2 |
|----|--------------|-------------------------|
|  A |        [2-3] |            [10.00-4.25] |
|  B | [6-7],[9-11] | [2.01-5.00],[9.00-4.25] |
|  C |        [6-8] |            [4.00-10.00] |
```

See [**SQL FIDDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1a6e/1/0).